# Search by date_created the students Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search, input

I want to search the "Students" table by "dateCreated" until today,  in a form input in laravel 4.2.

Here is the code I have written so far. I dont know how to query this and I get an error.

**View blade:**

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('date_created','...') }}
 <div class="input-group date">
 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
 {{ Form::input('date_created','date_created',null,['class'=>'form-control datepicker','data-date-format' => 'mm/dd/yy']) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function search(){

    $builder = User::query();.....

    if(Input::has('date_created')){
        $date = Input::get('date_created');
        $builder->select('*')
            ->where('Home_Students.dateCreated',$date)
            ->get();
    }


    $users = $builder->orderBy('home_lastname')->paginate(50);


        return View::make('user.show')->with(array('users' => $users));
    } //end function
```

**The error I am getting**

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

The date that is stored to the table has this form:

> 2010-11-10 10:54:07.077

To summarize, I want to ignore the time and just get the Students that are created, for example, from 3/07/2015 until today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a bit of the logic on this search. If you want dates **between** a given date and today, you need to reflect that in your `where()` clause, or use the `whereBetween()` function of Laravel. Also, I would format your dates to the same format as stored in the database, so try this:

```
if(Input::has('date_created')){
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created')));
    $builder->select('*')
        ->whereBetween('Home_Students.dateCreated',[$date, date("Y-m-d")])
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: i get this error again....pffff.....The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. (SQL: select * from [Home_Students] where [Home_Students].[home_dateCreated] between 11-02-2016 and 30-03-2016)

Comment: It worked and you were right the date formats where the problem...also i learned the whereBetween() function from you thanks a lot man !

Comment: @TimLewis btw I give my vote as also I was not aware of whereBetween.

Comment: No problem :) Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ No problem :P Yours should technically work too (as it seems hard to have a `date_created` value in the future, but yeah), `whereBetween()` is a handy function. `whereDate(..., "<=, ...)` is also another good alternative.

Comment: if that is ok with you I will update my answer by adding whereDate for eventully users that might find this useful

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Go for it :)

Comment: Can i have a second datepicker and not use whereBetween ? So i can pick for example from 2015-01-01 to 2016-01-01 ?

Comment: For sure, but that's still a `whereBetween`, (between 2015-01-01 and 2016-01-01) isn't it? You'd just have to link the second date picker to a php variable (like `$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('example')));`) and then replace the 2nd array input on `whereBetween`: `whereBetween('Home_Students.dateCreated',[$date, $date2])`

Comment: Thank you a lot im junior developer so i dont really know all the methods or the combinations i can do, i just code and learn in progress you have really helped me ! Hope you have a nice day man !

Comment: We all start out somewhere :) Laravel has some really great documentation, and there's always Stackoverflow if you don't quite understand something. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there; add `'<='` to your where

```
if(Input::has('date_created')){
        $date = Input::get('date_created');
        $builder->select('*')
            ->where('Home_Students.dateCreated','<=', $date)
            ->get();
    }
```

**EDIT** thanks to @TimLewis it is also possible to use `whereDate` and `whereBetween` in his answer.

What regards `whereDate`, it is posible to write it like this

```
if(Input::has('date_created')){
        $date = Input::get('date_created');
        $builder->select('*')
            ->whereDate('Home_Students.dateCreated','<=', $date)
            ->get();
    }
```

And remember to have the proper date format regarding to your database date standard, an example some thing like:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created')));
```

Btw in my test I have test it I have passed a string date format like:

```
$date = '2015-07-03';
```

And it worked as well.

Both methods have been tested and works in Laravel including @TimLewis answer as well.

Comment: try to simply things for test, try to comment if statement out and inject date manually like this `$date = '2015-07-03';` and after the that try send your querty to varibale `$output = $builder etc...` after that `dd($output)` and let me know what you get on your screen

Comment: i tried the Tim Lewis answer with whereBetween and it worked like a charm , also changed the formats dates to the format that the database is ...."Y-m-d" thank you for taking interest and helping !

Answer (score 1):

Although there is already an accepted answer thanks to @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ and @Tim Lewis I will post my progress on the code.

What I did was to give from 2 datepickers 3 options to search the users by the date_created.

**1)** From date (for example 2016-2-13) until today (the user fills out only the first datepicke, leaving the second empty).

**2)** Between two dates (for example 2016-2-13) until (for example 2016-3-20) (the user fills out the both datepickers).

**3)** From beginning until the date the user gives (for example 2016-2-13) (the user fills out only the second datepicker).

Here's the code, I hope this helps someone in the future:

```
if(Input::has('date_created_from')) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created_from')));
        $builder->select('*')
            ->whereBetween('Home_Students.dateCreated', [$date, date("Y-m-d")])
            ->get();
    }
        elseif(Input::has('date_created_from','date_created_untill')){
            $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created_from')));
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created_untill')));
            $builder->select('*')
                ->whereBetween('Home_Students.dateCreated', [$date,$date2])
                ->get();
            }
            elseif(Input::has('date_created_untill')){
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created_untill')));
            $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date_created_from')));
                $builder->select('*')
                ->whereBetween('Home_Students.dateCreated',[$date,$date2])
                ->get();
        }
```

To completely understand the code read the comments and the accepted (or other) answers!